# How to sum these values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have repeated invoice numbers, this happens because they may have different line items, each corresponding to an specific article that is sold. For example invoice 124116 contains two different articles pencils (line 1) with a value of 2,672.64 and rulers (line 2) with a value of 483.84. What I want, as the image depicts, is to get the total value for each invoice. In this example that would be 3,156.48.

Any help about how to do that??

[image]

Comment: I cant do that because I do not only have thiese fields shown in the picture but like 30 more, so pivot table in this case is a no go. thnaks for the answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this for my hours that I work for specific customers.

I have a table as follows:

```
Customername | Date | AmountOfHoursWorked
```

A different table has the following structure for specific dates and total hours worked on those days:

```
Date | AmountOfHoursWorked
```

In this table, I use `SUMIF`. The syntax of `SUMIF` is:

```
=SUMIF(range;criteria;sumrange)
```

So for example with a table:

```
=SUMIF(TableName[Day];[Date];Table1[HoursWorked])
```

Or for example to sum values from a full column (For example column B):

```
=SUMIF(B:B;B3;D:D);
```

Which means `"For all values in column B that are equal to the value of B3, Sum the corresponding values from column D into this cell"`

Which ends up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: given the picture I provided and copyng and paste next to it invoice and position as you said , in colum F - the one right after the ast of position- I write =SUMIF(A:A,A:A,C:C) , and what I get is the sum , thats right but repeated in position 1 and 2 in case of invoice 124116, or 6572.16 for position 1-4 for invoice 124117, where am I making the mistake?

Comment: The second argument `criteria` has to be 1 specific value. You're telling Excel to take the whole column as the criteria. Simply click the top row that has to contain the sum value, for example, look [Here](http://i.imgur.com/a3FJWCj.png). The rows mean Day, From, To, Amount of Hours and Comment. Let's say my Comment (Opmerking) row is my SUM row. For Row 3, my Criteria would be `C3`, because Cell `C3` Contains the date I want to look for. Column F contains the total amount of hours worked. This makes my `SUMIF` code the following: `=SUMIF(C:C,C3,F:F)`. Does this make it clear?

Comment: Yes, it makes total sense, but for some reason although I write =SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C) it doesnt work and gives me back the result I stated in my previous post. Nevertheless while waiting for an answer what I did is filtering leaving only position 1, then writing next to it, on an empty column , number 1 and copied it down. After that I removed the filter so i have columns with 1 and blank ones. Then next to it I wrote =IF(D2=1,C2,0). By doing that I fxed the problem . So your idea it is been of a great guidance! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use a pivot table. This is exactly its purpose

Drop the "Invoice" field in "Row labels"
Drop the "Sale Price" field in "Values". It should automatically set itself to "Sum of Sale Price", if not click on the drop-down, Value Field Settings, "Sum"

Et voila

Comment: the same as I answered before, cant use pivot tables for that, but thanks for your answer

Comment: You absolutely can use a pivot table with 30 fields or more

Comment: I know I can but what I meant is that is not convinient for me to use the pivot table to do that , as I m already doing sort of the same thing ith other values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `SUMIF` function?
Usage: `=SUMIF(range,criteria,sumrange)`
In this case `=SUMIF(the range of invoice numbers in the first column,the invoice number you want to sum,the sale price in column 3)`
Hope this is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Data > Consolidate Function, it's much simpler for sure.

Just place the Invoice numbers to the far left row.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGaq_biQ1B8

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask